# \xrightarrow{} is not working

Tags: xrightarrow

I'm trying to use \xrightarrow{} to include a partial over the arrow, but I seem to get a captial gamma in front of the arrow for some reason. I used the following:

```
\begin{equation}

...\xrightarrow{\qquad \partial_{p+2}}C_{p+1}\xrightarrow{\qquad \partial_{p+1}}C_p \xrightarrow{\qquad \partial_{p}}C_{p-1}\xrightarrow{\qquad \partial_{p-1}}...,

\end{equation}
```

but it compiles the following[image]

I have tried different compilers and loading both mathtools and amsmath but still I get the same output.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal (non)working code showing the problem? Just in case: did you load `amssymb`?

Comment: @Bernard I believe you mean `amsmath`; `amssymb` is not relevant for `\xrightarrow`. But without it one would get an undefined control sequence error and some blanks, so there is definitely something else going on here.

Comment: @campa: I just wondered whether `amsfonts` or amssymb` was not required for \xrightarrow.

Comment: you don't have those blank lines inside your actual equation do you?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the `xrightarrow` and `xRightarrow`, the package to use for this is `mathtools`. After troubleshooting in a separate file I found out that the problem was an interfering package, for me this was the `breqn` package to allow for line-breaking in equations. If this package is imported but not used throughout the rest of your work, I suggest disabling it and see if it works.